# System.Net.WebClient error can't download picture from the intranet

Tags: powershell, batch-file, webclient

I have a problem with powershell.

I am trying to download a gif from the intranet of our company with a BAT data, but it always say the following error:

[image]

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://domain.name/file.name','C:\file.name')"
```

can anyone help me?

edit: Here is the version of powershell:

sure here is the table:

```
 Name                           Value
 ----                           -----
 PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
 PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
 BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
 CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
 WSManStackVersion              3.0
 PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
 SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

The windows version is Windows 2008 R2

Best regards,

Xplosio

Comment: Well, does it work if you simply copy that URL into your browser?

Comment: Can you paste the the output of `$PSVersionTable` into the question? Older versions of .NET doesn't include support for TLS, so you may need to upgrade powershell

Comment: Judging by that shell, it's likely an EOL version Windows.

Comment: Yes when I send the request with Internet Explorer I get the gif

Comment: sure here is the table:

`Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1`

Comment: And the Windows Version?

Comment: The windows version is Windows 2008 R2